# I can't watch youtube videos in either Firefox or Chromium. version 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I can't watch youtube videos in either chromium browser or firefox. I've tried installing a plugin or flash player, but neither seem to work. I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm not real experienced on working on computers.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not real experienced with this kind of stuff. Where exactly do I run that?

Comment: You run it in the terminal, open the dash (hit the windows key) and type terminal, it will come up.

Comment: Well I tried that, and it didn't seem to help. Any more ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you reboot after you did it?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot after you reminded me. After I run the command and it runs through everything and stops, the bottom line says something like john-hill@johnhilldesktop$ or something close to that. Is it done after I see that? What should I do after that? I just closed the window. Maybe that was a mistake.

Comment: No, its done when it reaches that.

Comment: Ok, then I guess that didn't work either. Anything else I should try?

Comment: There are a lot of other questions on this site about it.  I would check them out.  Search for "flash not working"

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035661/playing-videos-in-firefox sudo apt install libavcodec-extra worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the fix! I uninstalled the Adobe flash player, and now it works. Not sure why, but now I can watch YouTube videos in either Firefox or Chrome, and websites that require flash work now as well. On YouTube, it still asks you to install a plugin, but then it plays it anyway. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that it is difficult to find a good browser that plays flash. So I installed this one https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/ and am much happier with the performance.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I first installed Ubuntu on this computer as a Wubi installation, but then I wanted to eliminate Windows so I downloaded a cd and did a full install that way. What's weird is that it worked ok with the Wubi install, but now I'm having this one issue with the cd installation. Before this install, it gave me an error when I played YouTube videos, but it still played. Now I get the same error but it doesn't play the video. It says "couldn't load plug-in". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Installing [ubuntu-restricted-extras [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras) fixed the problem for me. Click the above link to install it using Software Centre or use the command below to install using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```